Optimisation suggestions for Mann-Whitney U-Test in scipy?
I'm reading this with great interest 11 years later...
I have code that looks like this:
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

from tqdm import tqdm

# Basics
runs = 10000
scores = 100000
states = 1000

# Random scores
score = np.random.rand(runs * scores).reshape(runs, scores)
score.shape

# Random states
state = np.random.choice(
    [True, False],
    p=[0.01, 0.99],  # Roughly 1% True, 99% False (on average)
    size=scores * states,
).reshape(states, scores)
state.shape

muh_ps = np.zeros((runs, states))

for i in tqdm(range(runs), desc="Runs", total=runs):
    sc = score[i]

    for st in tqdm(range(states), desc="States", total=states):
        rp = sc[state[st]]
        rn = sc[~state[st]]

        u_statistic, u_pvalue = mannwhitneyu(rp, rn, alternative="two-sided")

        muh_ps[i, st] = u_pvalue

print(muh_ps)

$ pip freeze | grep scipy
scipy==1.14.1

I get the feeling that I shouldn't be looping over columns, but I'm not sure how I should be doing it...
Many thanks for pointers / optimisation suggestions, and sorry for the beginner question.
I've tried the 'naive' approach shown above, and I was expecting it to be 'slow'... actually, it's not bad:
test_man.py 
States: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:38<00:00, 25.86it/s]
States: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:38<00:00, 25.74it/s]
States: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:39<00:00, 25.36it/s]
States: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:37<00:00, 26.43it/s]
States: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:38<00:00, 26.14it/s]
Runs:   0%|                                         |   5/10000 [03:13<106:48:42, 38.47s/it]
States:  83%|██████████████████████████████████▌    |  827/1000 [00:27<00:06, 25.06it/s]

but it is going to take 5 days to finish at this rate...
I've tried passing in a boolean matrix to mannwhitneyu, but I must be doing something wrong. I've wondering about changing the data to CuPy, but I need guidance I think...

Can you make a reproducible example? e.g. you could randomly generate a boolean matrix, randomly generate the "score" column, and combine those into a single dataframe with the right shape. The more that the example is representative of your real problem, the better of answers you'll get.

The speedup you would be looking for is the potential to make 2D arrays a and b to pass into mannwhitneyu rather than looping over 1D arrays a and b. It looks like you can only make a and b 2D arrays if the number of elements where x[col] == True is the same every time; otherwise, the arrays would have to be ragged, which isn't allowed. Is the number of elements where x[col] == True always the same?

For such an intensive computation, a SIMD-friendly native multi-threaded code is needed (e.g. C/C++/Rust). Python will be inherently inefficient, more especially Scipy here (which AFAIK rebuild the merged array you split). I did it few years ago and the speed up was massive (2-3 order of magnitude faster for Python and something like 3-4 order of magnitude faster compared to R -- AFAIR on a mainstream ~40 server CPU).

"Python will be inherently inefficient...  I did it few years ago" - this is no longer necessarily true if a and b can be 2D arrays. The mannwhitneyu statistic calc has been vectorized so there are no loops, just NumPy array operations. It also has a much more efficient algorithm for p-value calculations than most libraries. In the not-so-distant future, it will support non-NumPy arrays like CuPy, so the calculations could even be done in parallel on a GPU. Certainly you can get faster with compiled languages, but it would be unfair to characterize SciPy as inherently inefficient here.

By the way, what version of SciPy are you using?

@NickODell, this is pretty much my data :-)

@MattHaberland, really sorry, I changed my notation since you made this comment. Hopefully the new version is clearer? Many thanks for any suggestions on how to optimize this... Actually, I should probably focus on the permutation test
https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/6324#issuecomment-2355662005

Note: 20x speedup below. This assumes your samples are big enough to use the asymptotic approximation for the p-value and that there are no ties. The same approach can work for an exact p-value calculation or a tie-corrected asymptotic approximation, but it might require some modifications.
At the core of your example is something like this:
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
rng = np.random.default_rng(2348923598235)

data = rng.random(size=100)
selectors = rng.random(size=(1000, 100)) > 0.5

def approach1():
    res = np.zeros((selectors.shape[0], 2))
    for j in range(selectors.shape[0]):
        res[j] = stats.mannwhitneyu(data[~selectors[j]], data[selectors[j]])
    return res.T

It's slow because you have to repeatedly perform the test with many different "selectors", and everything loops in Python.
Conceptually, you'd like to vectorize your code and avoid the explicit loop. Ideally, you would pass 2D arrays to mannwhitneyu, and perform the calculation along one of the two axes. This is tricky because your "selectors" have different numbers of Trues/Falses, so each slice of your 2D arrays would have different numbers of elements; they would be "ragged" arrays.
You can avoid the ragged array by passing rectangular arrays, masking out the elements you don't need with NaNs, and using nan_policy='omit'.
def approach2():
    x = np.broadcast_to(data, selectors.shape)
    x = x.copy()
    y = x.copy()
    x[selectors] = np.nan
    y[~selectors] = np.nan
    res = stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y, axis=-1, nan_policy='omit')
    return res.statistic, res.pvalue

This is not going to be much faster because under the hood, there will still be Python loops. (This is true for most scipy.stats functions with nan_policy='True', however many are vectorized and don't need to loop if nan_policy is not True. You can only tell by looking at the code, though.)
ref = approach1()
res2 = approach2()
np.testing.assert_allclose(res2, ref)

%timeit approach1()  # 384 ms ± 1.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit approach2()  # 151 ms ± 5.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

However, if you have a good understanding of how the mannwhitneyu code works, you can hack it together to avoid the loops and still ignore the NaNs. The main thing is generalizing the code to the case in which n1 and n2 (the number of real observations in each sample) are not simply length of the arrays along the axis; they are the number of non-NaNs.
def approach3(data, selectors):
    # assumes that statistic is to be calculated along
    # the last axis. Not tested when there are ties in the data.
    # Assumes that samples are big enough to use asymptotic
    # normal approximation for p-value.

    x, i = data, selectors
    x = np.broadcast_to(x, i.shape)
    x = x.copy()
    y = x.copy()

    x[i] = np.nan
    y[~i] = np.nan
    x.sort(axis=-1)
    x, y, xy = _broadcast_concatenate(x, y, axis=-1)

    n2 = np.count_nonzero(i, axis=-1)
    n1 = i.shape[-1] - n2

    ranks, t = _rankdata(xy, 'average', return_ties=True)
    R1 = np.take_along_axis(ranks.cumsum(axis=-1), n1[:, np.newaxis] - 1, axis=-1)
    R1 = R1[..., 0]
    U1 = R1 - n1 * (n1 + 1) / 2
    U2 = n1 * n2 - U1  # as U1 + U2 = n1 * n2
    U = np.maximum(U1, U2)  # multiply SF by two for two-sided test
    z = _get_mwu_z(U, n1, n2, t, axis=-1, continuity=True)
    p = stats.norm.sf(z) * 2
    p = np.clip(p, 0, 1)
    return U1, p

This produces the same results, and it is much faster.
ref = approach1()
res3 = approach3(data, selectors)
np.testing.assert_allclose(res3, ref)

%timeit approach3(data, selectors)  # 19.4 ms ± 95.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Such an approach could be used to perform the calculation using CuPy, if desired, but you might also need to copy-paste the definitions of the private functions and adapt them to use CuPy.

Stack exchange discourages the use of comments for thank yous and such. Instead, it is more useful for others reading the posts if votes are used to indicate useful posts and an answer is selected by the asker.

This might also be helpful to better understand your privileges when you post a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

I can confirm it works fine with ties:
data = rng.random(size=100).round(5)*10**5

# Add ties to the data by sampling from it
data = np.concatenate([data, data[rng.integers(0, len(data), size=10)]])


So I just tried this on the larger scale data (see my OP):
data2 = rng.random(size=100000); selectors2 = rng.random(size=(1000, len(data2))) > 0.5
And the trend is reversed unfortunately:
1 loop, best of 5: 5.97 sec per loop / 1 loop, best of 5: 8.11 sec per loop / 1 loop, best of 5: 26.1 sec per loop
Obviously I've confirmed what you initially saw: 1 loop, best of 5: 298 msec per loop / 2 loops, best of 5: 124 msec per loop / 20 loops, best of 5: 11.4 msec per loop

Probably takes time to allocate all the memory it needs because everything is processed together? I don't have another suggestion.

I've not had a chance to profile this... I'd assume that all the memory has to get allocated whatever the solution, so seems a unlikely... I'm not an expert though!

No, not all the memory needs to be allocated at the same time if you loop. Instead of either looping over all the samples individually or doing all in one big batch, you could try looping over small batches.
